# Doing some fairly basic sums with different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

**transactions** :  `Transaction_ID` `Datetime` `Giver_ID` `Recipient_ID` `Points`  `Category_ID` `Reason`

**rewards** :   `Reward_ID` `Title` `Description` `Image_URL` `Date_Inactive` `Stock_Count` `Cost_to_User` `Cost_to_System`

**purchases** : `Purchase_ID` `Datetime` `Reward_ID` `Quantity` `Student_ID` `Student_Name` `Date_DealtWith` `Date_Collected`

---

Staff members award students with *points* which becomes an entry into the *transactions* table, like this:

**`Transaction_ID` `Datetime` `Giver_ID` `Recipient_ID` `Points`    `Category_ID` `Reason`**
`8` `2011-09-07` `36761` `127963` `2` `1` `Excellent behaviour in behaviour unit`

Students can then purchase a *reward* which becomes an entry into the *purchases* table, like this:

**`Purchase_ID` `Datetime` `Reward_ID` `Quantity` `Student_ID` `Student_Name` `Date_DealtWith` `Date_Collected`**
`1570` `2012-05-30 12:46:36` `2` `1` `137616` `Bradley Richardson` `NULL` `NULL`

All of the *rewards* are stored manually in the *rewards* database table:

**`Reward_ID` `Title` `Description` `Image_URL` `Date_Inactive` `Stock_Count`   `Cost_to_User` `Cost_to_System`**
`1` `Lunch Time Queue Pass (month)` `Beat the queue and get to the hot food early!` `/user/74/167976.png` `2012-04-16 11:50:00` `0` `100` `0`

---

My question is this:
**Given a Reward_ID and a Student_ID, what SQL statement can I use to work out if the student has enough points to purchase the reward?**

I've previously done this in PHP, but I'd like to be able to do it using a single SQL statement if at all possible. The pseudo-code is something like `SELECT ( SumOfPointsEarned - SumOfPointsOfPurchasesMade )` but I have absolutely no idea how to go about that!

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use inline views. To do this

- Create a query that sums the points earned
- Create a query that sums the points spent
- Join thoes queries together (a left join in case they haven't spent anything yet)
- Do your subtraction

```
SELECT SumOfPointsEarned.Points - COALESCE(SumOfPointsOfPurchasesMade.Points, 0) AS CurrentPoints
FROM   
(
    SELECT SUM(Points) AS Points, Recipient_ID 
    FROM   transactions 
            WHERE Recipient_ID= 137642
    GROUP  BY Recipient_ID
) AS SumOfPointsEarned 
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT purchases.Student_ID,  SUM(rewards.Cost_to_User) AS Points 
        FROM   purchases 
            INNER JOIN rewards 
            ON purchases.Reward_ID = rewards.Reward_ID 
                    WHERE Student_ID = 137642
        GROUP  BY purchases.Student_ID
    ) AS SumOfPointsOfPurchasesMade 
    ON SumOfPointsEarned.Recipient_ID = SumOfPointsOfPurchasesMade.Student_ID
```

Comment: Hi Conrad. Thanks for that answer - I've edited it to spell COALESCE correctly and to include the `Student_ID` definition.

Comment: @dunc you're probably better off moving the Student ID references inside the Subqueries. Also you have to be careful of WHERE clauses referencing the RIGHT table in LEFT JOIN

Comment: @dunc also do you need the Reward.Cost_to_User for the target to be returned as well?

Comment: Ahah, thank you Sir! Don't worry too much about the Cost_to_User; I've decided to implement that separately using PHP :)

Answer (score 0):

transactions : Transaction_ID Datetime Giver_ID Recipient_ID Points Category_ID Reason

rewards : Reward_ID Title Description Image_URL Date_Inactive Stock_Count Cost_to_User Cost_to_System

purchases : Purchase_ID Datetime Reward_ID Quantity Student_ID Student_Name Date_DealtWith Date_Collected

---

SELECT SUM(a.Points) Total_Points, b.Reward_ID, b.Student_ID, b.Student_Name from transactions a
inner join purchases b
ON a.Student_ID = b.Student_ID;

this should be one table, do an insert into points_table and then you can join that on the rewards table using a WHERE Total_Points > Cost_to_User...