# Multiple table, multiple column query

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

**transactions** :  `Transaction_ID` `Datetime` `Giver_ID` `Recipient_ID` `Points`  `Category_ID` `Reason`

**rewards** :   `Reward_ID` `Title` `Description` `Image_URL` `Date_Inactive` `Stock_Count` `Cost_to_User` `Cost_to_System`

**purchases** : `Purchase_ID` `Datetime` `Reward_ID` `Quantity` `Student_ID` `Student_Name` `Date_DealtWith` `Date_Collected`

---

Staff members award students with *points* which becomes an entry into the *transactions* table, like this:

**`Transaction_ID` `Datetime` `Giver_ID` `Recipient_ID` `Points`    `Category_ID` `Reason`**
`8` `2011-09-07` `36761` `127963` `2` `1` `Excellent behaviour in behaviour unit`

Students can then purchase a *reward* which becomes an entry into the *purchases* table, like this:

**`Purchase_ID` `Datetime` `Reward_ID` `Quantity` `Student_ID` `Student_Name` `Date_DealtWith` `Date_Collected`**
`1570` `2012-05-30 12:46:36` `2` `1` `137616` `Bradley Richardson` `NULL` `NULL`

All of the *rewards* are stored manually in the *rewards* database table:

**`Reward_ID` `Title` `Description` `Image_URL` `Date_Inactive` `Stock_Count`   `Cost_to_User` `Cost_to_System`**
`1` `Lunch Time Queue Pass (month)` `Beat the queue and get to the hot food early!` `/user/74/167976.png` `2012-04-16 11:50:00` `0` `100` `0`

---

**My question is this:**

What SQL statement can I use to return **Student Name, Points Earned, Points Spent, Points Remaining**?

I asked [a similar question a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836001/doing-some-fairly-basic-sums-with-different-tables), which offered the following statement. However, upon inspection, it doesn't appear to be entirely accurate - specifically **Points Spent** isn't working correctly.

```
SELECT  Recipient_ID AS StudentID,
        SumOfPointsOfPurchasesMade.Points AS PurchasesMade,
        SumOfPointsEarned.Points AS PointsEarned,
        SumOfPointsEarned.Points - COALESCE(SumOfPointsOfPurchasesMade.Points, 0) AS CurrentPoints
FROM   
(
    SELECT SUM(Points) AS Points, Recipient_ID 
    FROM   transactions
    GROUP  BY Recipient_ID
) AS SumOfPointsEarned 
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT purchases.Student_ID,  SUM(rewards.Cost_to_User) AS Points 
        FROM   purchases 
            INNER JOIN rewards 
            ON purchases.Reward_ID = rewards.Reward_ID
        GROUP  BY purchases.Student_ID
    ) AS SumOfPointsOfPurchasesMade 
    ON SumOfPointsEarned.Recipient_ID = SumOfPointsOfPurchasesMade.Student_ID
WHERE SumOfPointsEarned.Points < SumOfPointsOfPurchasesMade.Points
ORDER BY `CurrentPoints`  DESC
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use an [outer join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) to combine the tables, then group by student:

```
SELECT purchases.Student_Name                               AS `Student Name`,
       SUM(transactions.Points)                             AS `Points Earned`,
       SUM(rewards.Cost_to_User)                            AS `Points Spent`,
       SUM(transactions.Points) - SUM(rewards.Cost_to_User) AS `Points Remaining`
FROM   transactions
  LEFT JOIN purchases ON purchases.Student_ID = transactions.Recipient_ID
  LEFT JOIN rewards   USING (Reward_ID)
GROUP BY purchases.Student_ID
ORDER BY `Points Remaining` DESC
```

Comment: Good answer, but with MySQL it would be better to use INNER join where possible (outer ones often get REALLY slow). My point is change the joins to `LEFT JOIN (purchases INNER JOIN rewards USING(Reward_ID)) ON /*...*/` as long as any purchase always has a connected reward row.

Comment: When I try to use your statement, my MySQL server times out... :) I don't know if it's because there's ~100,000 rows in the transactions table? Is there an alternative?

Comment: @dunc: Do you have indexes on your join columns?  Have you tried the optimisation suggested by Slava?

Comment: @dunc: To be clear, you have indexes on `purchases.Student_ID`, `rewards.Reward_ID` and a compound index on `transactions.(Recipient_ID, Reward_ID)`?

Answer (score 1):

I've stupidly realised that a tiny mistake from the other post fixes the problem I was having:

```
SELECT SumOfPointsEarned.Points - COALESCE(SumOfPointsOfPurchasesMade.Points, 0) AS CurrentPoints
FROM   
(
    SELECT SUM(Points) AS Points, Recipient_ID 
    FROM   transactions 
            WHERE Recipient_ID= 137642
    GROUP  BY Recipient_ID
) AS SumOfPointsEarned 
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT purchases.Student_ID,  SUM(rewards.Cost_to_User * purchases.Quantity) AS Points 
        FROM   purchases 
            INNER JOIN rewards 
            ON purchases.Reward_ID = rewards.Reward_ID 
                    WHERE Student_ID = 137642
        GROUP  BY purchases.Student_ID
    ) AS SumOfPointsOfPurchasesMade 
    ON SumOfPointsEarned.Recipient_ID = SumOfPointsOfPurchasesMade.Student_ID
ORDER BY CurrentPoints ASC
```

This one line was the problem:

`SUM(rewards.Cost_to_User * purchases.Quantity) AS Points`

No multiplication of quantity. Doh!